# Парсер, вытаскивающий следующий int из текстового файла, игнорируя комментарии

Tags: java, парсер, java-8

Нужно написать метод, который кушал бы текстовый файл на вход, а на выход отдавал бы следующее число, находящееся не в комментариях. Не знаю, как это сделать, потому что, если парсить по пробелам, то можно наткнуться на число в комментариях.

```
  30    30
1
15
11
10 9
//

10 10
12 10
15 10     //  14
7 11                                   //текстовый комментарий
14 11
8 12
11 12
7 13
8 14
9 14
```

Вот вывод: 30, 30, 1, 15, 11, 10, 9, 10, 10, 12, 10, 15, 10, 7, 11 и так далее
Запятые здесь просто для удобоварения, лучше, если это будет String[]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите сделать. В вопросе у вас пример ввода, добавьте пример вывода для этого ввода.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, добавил.

Comment: Читать строки по одной умеете? Если да, то вопрос сводится к тому как вырезать комментарий из строки. На такой вопрос ответ дадут быстрее.

Comment: @Иван считать по сроке файл в цикле. Текущую строку разбить по пробелам, все пустые или null элементы в массиве удалить. Остальное проверить число ли это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String line: Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C://file.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) { // где лежит файл
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s")));
            arr.removeAll(Arrays.asList(" ", null));
            for(String r: arr) {
                if(r.matches("^[0-9]+$")) {
                    result.add(Integer.parseInt(r));
                }
            }
        }
```